# How to display a column from the include file in a DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

So my code has a list that loads into the DataGridView.

```
Public Shared Function EmployeeList(ByVal EmployeeID As String) As List(Of TrainingRecord)
    Using context = New iTracContext
        Dim RecordList As New List(Of TrainingRecord)

        RecordList = context.TrainingRecords.Include("TrainingReference").Where(Function(e) e.EmployeeID = EmployeeID And e.due_date.Year = TrainingManagerForm.YR).ToList
        Return RecordList

    End Using
End Function
```

I have the `include("TrainingReference")` also loaded. I want to show in a DataGridView a column from the `TrainingReference` but cant seem to get it. I have however been able to hide some of the columns.

```vb
Select Case fMode
    Case OpMode.Edit
        ReferenceList = TrainingReference.LoadAll(CategoryComboBox.Text, GroupsComboBox.Text, OwnerComboBox.Text, CoursesInActiveCheckbox.Checked)
        ReferencesGrid.DataSource = ReferenceList
    Case OpMode.View
        EmployeeList = TrainingRecord.EmployeeList(EmployeeComboBox.SelectedValue)
        ReferencesGrid.DataSource = EmployeeList
        ReferencesGrid.Columns("id").Visible = False
        ReferencesGrid.Columns("referenceid").Visible = False
        ReferencesGrid.Columns("employeeid").Visible = False
        ReferencesGrid.Columns("Completed").Visible = False
        ReferencesGrid.Columns("employee").Visible = False
        ReferencesGrid.Columns("trainingreference").Visible = False
        ReferencesGrid.Columns("trainingreference")

End Select

retrieveEmployeeDetails()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a list of [Anonymous Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/anonymous-types) to create objects that include whatever you want to display in the DGV from your generic classes. I don't know your classes nor their members. So, let's assume that you want to display the employeeid, employee, and trainingreference only from the list of items returned by:

```
EmployeeList = TrainingRecord.EmployeeList(EmployeeComboBox.SelectedValue)
```

Then you could create anonymous list as follow:

```
Dim AnonymousList As New List(Of Object)

For Each item In EmployeeList
    AnonymousList.Add(New With {item.employeeid, item.employee, item.trainingreference})
Next

DataGridView1.DataSource = AnonymousList
```

And here is the output of a quick test:

[image: The Output]

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's IT! Never thought of creating an anon list (small minds). Thanks!!!

Comment: Glad to help and I appreciate your support. Keep it up.